# How to make ImageView Clear and Hazy based on RecyclerView position on Scrolling?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am doing app where I have to make my half screen visible and half sreen Dull. When I start Scrolling,  First View should be clear and else in Hazy Manner. as soon as I scroll them and first position gone from screen Second Position Item must be Clear and others in Hazy means dull. How can I do ? 
What I tried..

**My Adapter**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(PageCircleIndiAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final PageModels pageModels = pageList.get(position);
    if (pageList.get(position) != null) {

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(pageModels.resourceId);
        if (position == 0) {
            holder.imageView.setAlpha(1f);
        } else if (position == pageList.size() - 1) {
            holder.imageView.setAlpha(1f);
            pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
        } else if (position > firstVisible && position < lastVisible) {
            pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
            holder.imageView.setAlpha(0.2f);
        }
        if (position == pageList.size() - 1) {
            pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
        } else {
            holder.imageView.setAlpha(0.2f);
            pageCircleIndicator.changeIndicator(position);
        }

    }

}
```

**My ScrollView on MainActivity**

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();

            int firstVisible = manager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
            int lastVisible = manager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();
            Log.i("TAG", "onScrolled: " + firstVisible);
            Log.i("TAG", "Last Index: " + lastVisible);
            pageAdapter.changeItem(firstVisible, lastVisible);

        }

    });
    createIndicator();
    pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a blur?

Comment: @TheAndroidDev pleas egive me idea how to use

Comment: have a look at https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript